# Pass $_SESSION variables to included file

Tags: php, file, session, include

i have a first PHP file:
/home/www/subdomain1.domain.tld/file.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['foo']='bar';   
    include "/home/www/subdomain2.domain.tld/foo2.php";
 ?>
```

and /home/www/subdomain2.domain.tld/foo2.php:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['foo'];
?>
```

The "include" in the first file generates a "500 Internal Server Error", i think it's because session variables are not passed to included files, how can i fix that?

Thank you
Alex

EDIT:
I **must** use session variables in order to use these variables on every php file on subdomain2.

Comment: Which PHP version are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use sessions when including a file. It is all the same request with the same namespace.

file.php:

```
$foo = 'bar';

include 'foo2.php';
```

foo2.php

```
echo $foo; // returns 'bar'
```

Comment: i forgot to say that i have to use these variables in other files that are not included by these two files, so i must use sessions in order to share my variables with all pages on the subdomain2

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be starting the session in the second file.  Since the session was started in file.php, it is already available to foo2.php.

The error may be because PHP output a warning that the session was already started.

For debugging, add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the beginning of your first PHP script.

You should just be able to do:

**file.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['foo']='bar';   
    include "/home/www/subdomain2.domain.tld/foo2.php";
```

**foo2.php**

i have a first PHP file: /home/www/subdomain1.domain.tld/file.php

and /home/www/subdomain2.domain.tld/foo2.php:

```
<?php 
// session_start();  // remove, do not need this here
echo $_SESSION['foo'];
```

Comment: i have error reporting enabled by default, i also thought that it was not enabled and i added error_reporting(E_ALL), but it just generates 500 error without giving any information.
And i tried removing the "session_start" at the top of the second file, but it does not work

Comment: Check the server error log file, there should be some explanation of the error there then.

Comment: no logs on the server, i checked them just after the 500 error came out, my home/logs folder is empty

Comment: Are you running Apache?  If so check the apache error_log file, that's where it would be.

Comment: [Sun Oct 21 21:27:00 2012] [error] [client \*.\*.\*.\*] File does not exist: /services/users/.../www/subdomain/favicon.ico

but that's not the problem, if i just remove my "include" everything works perfectly.

Comment: Ok so no PHP errors in there?  Does the file you including have correct permissions (644 owned by your user?)

Comment: Try 644, PHP scripts should just be 644.  It probably isn't an issue but security software like suhosin or suExec would disallow a script with 755 permissions from running.

Comment: Does the error message change if you switch include to be require_once ?  Are you 100% sure the path to the file is correct?

Comment: if i change to require_once i get exactly the same error, with no message, simply "500 Internal Server Error". And yes, i'm 100% sure the path is correct, cause if i change the path it says "Error: could not find file for include"